# Pytorch-Forecasting N-Beats model with SELU() activation function?

Tags: pytorch, forecasting, relu

I am working at **timeseries forecasting**, and I've using the PyTorch lib **[`pytorch-forecasting`](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** lately. If you didn't know it, try it. It's great.

I am interested in `SELU` activation function for Self-Normalizing-Networks (SNNs, [see, e.g., the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.SELU.html#torch.nn.SELU)). As **I didn't find any N-Beats corrected to use SELU** and its requirements (i.e. AlphaDropout, proper weights init), **I made an implementation myself**.

It would be great if **any of you with experience** with these concepts -NBeats architecture, `pytorch-forecasting`, or SELU()- **could review whether everything is right in my implementation**.

**My implementation here**: https://gist.github.com/pnmartinez/fef1f488497fa85a2cc1626af2a5b4bd

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code reviews are better suited in [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi @Berriel, you are right: you can find it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259626/pytorch-forecasting-n-beats-model-with-selu-activation-function)